# WPF DataGrid ItemsSource many class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have many classes like this:

```
public  class ClassA
{
    public decimal ID_A { get; set; } = 0;
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; } = "";
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; } = "";
}

public class ClassB
{
    public decimal ID_B { get; set; } = 0;
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; } = "";
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; } = "";
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; } = "";
}
```

These classes should be shown in DataGrid. For tests, I just added a window containing two buttons. The first contains:

```
List<ClassA> a = new List<ClassA>()
{
    new ClassA { ID_A = 1, MyProperty1 = "Ap1", MyProperty2 = "p1"} ,
    new ClassA { ID_A = 2, MyProperty1 = "Ap2", MyProperty2 = "p2"}

};
ListaDanych FLista = new ListaDanych(a);
FLista.Show();
```

And the second one:

```
List<ClassB> b = new List<ClassB>()
{
    new ClassB { ID_B = 1, MyProperty1 = "Bp1", MyProperty2 = "p1", MyProperty3 = "3"} ,
    new ClassB { ID_B = 2, MyProperty1 = "Bp2", MyProperty2 = "p2", MyProperty3 = "3"}
};
ListaDanych FLista = new ListaDanych(b);
FLista.Show();
```

These two buttons just generate lists with tests data and run my second window.

In the second window, I just add a constructor for each class:

```
private List<ClassA> _MojeDaneA;
private List<ClassB> _MojeDaneB;

public ListaDanych(List<ClassA> ListaDanych)
{
    _MojeDaneA = ListaDanych;
    InitializeComponent();
    DGDane.ItemsSource = ListaDanych;
}

public ListaDanych(List<ClassB> ListaDanych)
{
    _MojeDaneB = ListaDanych;
    InitializeComponent();
    DGDane.ItemsSource = ListaDanych;
}
```

But can I do this in more generic way and just add one constructor for all existing classes?

And the second question: How can I add custom headers for DataGrid, based on the class type passed in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Object doesn't work, but IEnumerable is working.

This is my code now:

```
public ListaDanych(Type Typ, IEnumerable ListaDanych) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    if(Typ == typeof(ClassA))
    {
        UCDataGrid_A uCDataGrid_A = new UCDataGrid_A();
        Siatka.Children.Add(uCDataGrid_A);
        uCDataGrid_A.Dane.ItemsSource = ListaDanych;
    }
    if (Typ == typeof(ClassB))
    {
        UCDataGrid_B uCDataGrid_B = new UCDataGrid_B();
        Siatka.Children.Add(uCDataGrid_B);
        uCDataGrid_B.Dane.ItemsSource = ListaDanych;
    } 
}
```

And UCDataGrid_A is just custom controls. It contains:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTest.Klasy.UCDataGrid_A"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest.Klasy"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" d:DesignHeight="261.292" d:DesignWidth="654.832">            

        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="Dane">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding OK}" Header="OK" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID_A}" Header="ID" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyProperty1}" Header="Prop 1" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyProperty2}" Header="Prop 2" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

</UserControl>
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it works.

And for me, it has two advantages:

1. I can see how my DataGrid looks like
2. I can have a definition for each class in a separate file

Comment: This does not *look* like an answer. If it is, please make it look like one. [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code for a more generic constructor and custom headers in your `ListaDanych` window:

```cs
public partial class ListaDanych : Window
{
    private object _dataSource;

    public ListaDanych(object dataSource)
    {
        _dataSource = dataSource;
        InitializeComponent();
        DGDane.ItemsSource = _dataSource;

        SetHeaders();
    }

    private void SetHeaders()
    {
        if (_dataSource is List<ClassA>)
        {
            DGDane.Columns[0].Header = "ID_A";
            DGDane.Columns[1].Header = "MyProperty1";
            DGDane.Columns[2].Header = "MyProperty2";
        }
        else if (_dataSource is List<ClassB>)
        {
            DGDane.Columns[0].Header = "ID_B";
            DGDane.Columns[1].Header = "MyProperty1";
            DGDane.Columns[2].Header = "MyProperty2";
            DGDane.Columns[3].Header = "MyProperty3";
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, you have a single constructor that accepts an `object` parameter. Based on the type of the object, it sets the data source for the `DataGrid` and customizes the column headers accordingly. The `SetHeaders` method checks the type of the data source and assigns headers based on the type.

Remember to adjust the column indices and header names according to your classes' properties. This approach avoids duplicating code for each class constructor and provides a more generic solution.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.  I try use List<object> but doesn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, justyce jaelen!

Your 7 answers so far appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). *Six* of those seven have comments from users indicating issues with the answer, which demonstrates why [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!